# How to validate SHA256 hash with a message + nonce?

Tags: r, sha256

In R I can generate a 256hash with the following function.

```
> sha256 ( 'R is great')
[1] "3df43bfb52a031873872284bec472cdd8e1fe8803a6ba936c2446d4d920fd592"
```

however I know that if I want to get a hash with 4 leading zeros the nounce is
`62137` and the final has is `000099bed1e274d13fd4b9864d52ee6f2a8d1f93941f8283b879ba949250b01c`

however I want to show this in R. But when I add the nounce to the previous function it does not produce the same hash.

```
> sha256 ( '000099bed1e274d13fd4b9864d52ee6f2a8d1f93941f8283b879ba949250b01cR is great')
[1] "e1c828213b2463986fe8a5557c4c7b39ea42b792de1bb2a22c50dc2472f7ac6f"
```

how do I add the nonce to the message to produce the same hash?

source: [image]
https://andersbrownworth.com/blockchain/blockchain
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dug around in the [source code of the example](https://github.com/anders94/blockchain-demo/blob/master/views/blockchain.pug). The function `getText` generates the string that is hashed. `getText` adds the following elements:

- block number
- nonce
- data
- previous hash

In R, you can reproduce it with:

```
sha256( '262137R is great000015783b764259d382017d91a36d206d0600e2cbb3567748f46a33fe9297cf')
[1] "000099bed1e274d13fd4b9864d52ee6f2a8d1f93941f8283b879ba949250b01c"
```